# Debugging ruby child process node js

Tags: node.js, ruby, child-process

I am running a Ruby script as a node js child process with the following code

```
              const constructDS = childProcess.exec('ruby ./constructOSW.rb',function(error,stdout,stderr){
                  console.log(stdout);
                  console.log("Ruby StdErrors:", stderr);
                  console.log("Ruby Errors", error);
              });
              //
              constructDS.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(nonGeoDesignSpace))
              constructDS.stdin.end();
```

I am having trouble working out how to launch an ruby debugger - (ideally an ide - but pry will do) when the script runs.

Any pointers and/or example code would be most appreciated

Comment: this is a pretty interesting quetion. If you add a pry call to the code, and run this, do you see the pry output through the `console.log(stdout)` line? Are you trying to do this for the sake of debugging, or it's actually part of the function of the program?

Comment: @max pleaner I am running it for the sake of debugging - unfortunately when I run ruby with ruby pry -r I dont get any output from stdout

Comment: ok, here's a rule of thumb. You should never try and interact with a breakpoint when it's behind a child process. It is simply not going to work. Possibly you could hack together some way to make it work, but it's highly unlikely to be worth the effort. It's a much better idea to try running the Ruby script by itself (without the Node / child process wrapper), that way breakpoints work seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question as @Max pleaner suggested there is no way to run pry when you are running ruby as a child process.

So instead I write the stdin into ruby as a json to file (I call it argsIntoRuby.json) and then I run a batch with the following
"ruby.exe rubyscript.rb < argsIntoRuby.json" in this way I can run pry on ruby with the stdin.